# Access Network Share folder from IIS 8.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-8

I am developing web application to access network share folder file and download the file. my application is working properly in development PC, once i publish to the IIS, cannot access the folder path and getting error  **" Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password."**
This is the sample code i have used to access the folder

```
WebClient request = new WebClient();
string Directroypath = @"\\192.168.1.20\Sacn_docs\Scan_Old\SCAN CR\";
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin","pwd","192.168.1.20");
```

i cant find the proper solution . please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Why are you using a WebClient to access an SMB path?

Comment: i cant find any other code